# Difference between send/sendfile and fprintf and which is better? c socket

Tags: c, sockets

I have 2 server socket example in C.  One is using the send function to send data while other is using fprintf.  What is the difference between the 2 and which is better?

```
len = send(peer_socket, file_size, sizeof(file_size), 0);
```

versus

```
FILE *fpIn =    fdopen(sd, "r");

fprintf(fpOut, "Processing fd %d on server.", sd);
```

I am looking to send a file over socket which one should I pick in this case?

Comment: Neither of these sends the contents of the file.  And they don't send remotely the same information.  What are you trying to do and why would you think these would work?

Comment: nvm I solved it by using ths sendfile from first example as I just mostly copy pasted the original code